# apoc.convert.toString is an unknown function, even though apoc is loaded and enabled in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

## Question and context

I am trying to import some json into a neo4j database. I'm an almost complete n00b on neo4j so the script itself (see below) may be more than a bit dubious, but that's not my problem now. My problem is much simpler: When running the script I get the error message `Unknown function 'apoc.convert.toString' (line 4, column 69 (offset: 196)) "CALL apoc.create.node(n.labels, apoc.map.setKey(n.properties, 'id', apoc.convert.toString(n.InternalId))) YIELD node` ... and I simply don't understand why.   I'm running from neo4j desktop using a 5.11.0 database.  Nothing special. Just created the database, installed apoc from the desktop app, created an apoc.conf with a single `apoc.import.file.enabled=true` to enable apoc. When only reading the file I do get a very large json file read in, so apoc as such seems to be working, but applying the `apoc.convert.toString` function does not work.

I don't know what to do to progress, please help :-)

## The code that causes the failure

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///foo.json") YIELD value
WITH value.nodes AS nodes, value.links AS rels
UNWIND nodes AS n
CALL apoc.create.node(n.labels, apoc.map.setKey(n.properties, 'id', apoc.convert.toString(n.InternalId))) YIELD node
WITH rels, apoc.map.mergeList(COLLECT({id: apoc.convert.toString(n.InternalId), node: node})) AS nMap
UNWIND rels AS r
CALL apoc.create.relationship(nMap[apoc.convert.toString(r.Source)], r.type, r.properties, nMap[apoc.convert.toString(r.Target)]) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Answer (score 2):

but the new toString() does not convert objects to string. Is there another function that converts objects to String
Examples
this statement apoc.convert.toString(apoc.convert.toMap(nodes)) worked before with new function toString(apoc.convert.toMap(nodes) it does not work

Answer (score 1):

`apoc.convert.toString()` was [removed in Neo4j 5.1](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/deprecations-and-additions/#apoc-deprecations-additions-removals-5.1).

You should use the [toString()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/#functions-tostring) function instead.